# Do I leave a revised question closed even though it falls out of scope for a different reason than the original closure reason?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

I have been through a few re-open requests and some shared a similar issue.

Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3106364)

It was originally closed as unclear. Then the OP changes the question but his edit still makes it a very poor question with no research shown and the answer could be as simple as *yes* or *no* - only if the question didn't get closed.

I judge looking at the new(*revised*) question ignoring the original closure reason. Even though the revised question still doesn't make a good question and would probably get closed very quickly I just leave it closed with the old closure reason.

- Am I doing the right thing or should we re-open and let it get closed
  for a new - more appropriate reason?

The answer seems obvious: leave it closed, but

- is this how all of you process re-open queue?

Note: *I am asking because sometimes I've noticed others voting to re-open such cases and I want to confirm that I am on the same page as everyone else*

Comment: I've seen a few questions that were rightfully put on hold, but for the wrong reason. I guess the best action is to "Leave Closed" and add a comment.

Comment: Probably depends heavily on if the new close reason would be "duplicate", then a close reopen is helpful

Comment: I sometimes (infrequently, because it's tedious) flag such questions for mod attention, explaining the issue and asking to consider re-close with more appropriate reason

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My rule of thumb is "don't re-open if it's still a bad question". I think of it as a variant of the "don't migrate bad questions" rule.

If you feel like showing a new user the ropes, you can leave a comment explaining why their revision is not helpful.

It would be nice if we had a "leave closed but for a different reason" option, but that would just add another option to the process - and Stack Exchange tries (rightfully) to keep the UI as simple as possible.

There is also a practical consideration: if the question is re-opened so that you close it for a different reason, it will enter the Close Votes review queue - which is far too big already.

The comment of @Richard Tingle made me realize there should be 1 exception: I agree with him that if the new close reason would be "duplicate", re-opening and re-closing could be helpful. The link to the duplicate question that gets added after re-closing the question, could be useful for future visitors.

Comment: when I see that edit of (still worthy to stay closed) has invalidated current reason too much, I typically flag it to moderator attention asking to re-close with a more appropriate reason

Comment: Add the flag for moderator attention option as an answer